# String is not rendering as html in angularJs using $sce

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm getting the following data from server `<span>text</span>`.

I'm using the following function in my controller

```
$scope.getHtml = function (html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
};
```

and in the html as follows

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-bind-html="getHtml(vm.profileData.htmltext)">
```

After doing this I am getting this in view, it is not rendering :

```
<span>text</span>
```

Please tell me where I'm getting things wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: how you setting `vm.profileData.htmltext` ? can you share a bit of more code?

Comment: I'm getting the data from server as string as follows, and set it in vm.profileData.htmltext.
vm.profileData.htmltext = '&lt;span&gt;text&lt;/span&gt;'

Comment: may be you should do html entity decode before assigning to html text. i am not sure you can try

Comment: Post your $sce.trustAsHtml function.

Comment: This is an in-build function from angular-sanitize, $sce
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: `vm.profileData.htmltext = angular.element('<div></div>').html(response_from_server).text();` may work

Comment: @RajeshDan put **console.log(html)** in getHtml function. What is the otput on console?

Comment: Please see this plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/YkiQZptEY6iosJli09yj?p=preview

Comment: @VVK the output of console.log(html) is
&lt;span&gt;text&lt;/span&gt;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i mention you need a html entity decode

```
 $scope.html = angular.element('<div></div>').html('&lt;i&gt;text&lt;/i&gt;').text();
 $scope.getHtml = function() {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
};
```

[plunker url](http://plnkr.co/edit/xUKCWO9ViBdVsEk8qsxA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you..It worked.. But I don't have reputation to upvote it.. Sorry for that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this code for this.

```
function htmlDecode(str) {
     return $('<textarea />').html(str).text();   
}  

// angular js
$sce.trustAsHtml(htmlDecode(html));
```